# Using Z scores in real life to predict increase in EPC

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I just did a test for a company for a job interview. I had information regarding Company Madeup, for who I was doing some analysis. I found out that, over the course of 2018, Company Madeup's website had made money for Shop Madeup. 
I created a table with this information, which had the following headers:

> Year - Month - Total Clicks Sent to Shop - Total Commission made by Company

From here, I worked out how much commission was earned per click (i.e total commission/total clicks), for each month.

Even though the data was for 2018, I wanted to be a bit more proactive and use my analysis to predict something for 2019. What I wanted to do was to predict earning per click (EPC) for 2019, based on trends seen in 2018.

The way I started this was, after calculating all the earnings per click (EPC) for 2018, I created a distribution model (as I now have a mean and standard deviation).

I then worked out Z scores for each of the EPC value. This would let me see how good the EPC for that month is, in relation to the rest of the year. The aim was that using the Z score, I could calculate the probability that EPC in the next year would increase by the same amount. I never got round to this but I want to ask a few questions on it as I have an interview tomorrow to go through my result, so hopefully can talk about it there.

Is that sound reasoning or have I completely missed a step? Is there an alternative way to do this?

As a follow up also: I calculated my Z score for one month to be 2.46, which translates to a probability of .69%. Does this mean that probability that EPC in 2019 will beat the EPC in 2018 is 0.69%?

Comment: There's really not enough information here to analyze this.  You allude to "trends" but then you don't appear to make an effort to model them.  For instance, many industries are cyclic.  Heating oil sells a lot better in cold months.  It would be silly to use data collected from the winter months to estimate heating oil sales in midsummer.  You have to model the cyclic trends.  In general, making predictions  based on statistical data requires a model of the situation, and I don't see from the above what model you are assuming.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. As part of a restriction with the test, I was limited to one years worth of data (Jan - Dec). I could use the assumption that trends were fairly cyclic, i.e if I saw in an increase in EPC in November, I can assume I'd see that the following year (due to yearly promotions).

Comment: The point is:  you need to state clearly what assumptions you are making and explain them.  On one year's data it's tough to see cyclic patterns, but of course you know what industry the firm is in...are other firms in that industry cyclic?  Are there patterns in the industry as a whole?  As I say, it's hard to say much with so little information.

Comment: Basic questions to ask:  what does linear regression show?  Is there a definable drift?  How convincing is the evidence for a drift?  If you know enough to generate a plausible model of returns you can do a more informed regression than a simple line.

Comment: To stress: had I set this sort of task as an interviewer, I would be most interested in knowing what assumptions you made and why you made them.  After listening to that, I'd ask you what you would do with more data.  What tests would you run to confirm, refine, or reject the assumptions you made, and so on.  Usually the calculations themselves are quite easy...it's interpreting them that's difficult.

Comment: @lulu that's actually amazing advice. Thank you so much for that, I really do appreciate it!